# What values of Avogadro's Number did Jean Perrin come up with?

Tags: physics, chemistry

I am currently plundering the contents of the $1969$ reprint of the 2nd edition of *Data and Formulae for Engineering Students* published by Pergamon International (authors J.C. Anderson, D.M. Hum, B.G. Neal, J.H. Whitelaw) which I found in my bookshelf.

In chapter 3: Physical Constants, it states:

Avogadro's number $\qquad \text N \qquad = 6.023 \times 10^{26} \ / \text {kg mole}$

It is understood that the definition of Avogadro's number (henceforth here $N_0$) was rationalised in 1971 to be the amount of substance that contains as many elementary entities as there are atoms in $12$ grams of carbon-$12$, but it is unclear (from the sources I have managed to find) what that number actually was, merely that it was known to be approximately $6.02 \times 10^{23}$.

It is also understood that the current definition of $N_0$ (as exactly $6.02214076 \times 10^{23}$) happened in 2019.

I am interested to know where the $6.023$ might have come from in the above book, or whether it's a mistake brought about by a conflation of the 2nd and 3rd decimal places (23) with the exponent of $10$. It is remarkably tempting to remember the $23$-ness of Avogadro's number and accidentally apply it to the mantissa.

The question is: what values of $N_0$ were in circulation *before* the 2019 redefinition? In particular, what value of $N_0$ was determined by Jean Perrin (who actually did most of the initial hard work of measuring it)?

It occurs to me that if it "suddenly" changed from $6.023$ to $6.022...$, that's a (relatively) large change to standards which in general are known to an accuracy of well under parts per million. That is to my mind something of a discrepancy.

Comment: In an older publication from behind the Iron Curtain I see *two* values for Avogadro's number: $N_{\mathrm{A}}^{\mathrm{Ph}} = (6.02252 \pm 0.00016) \cdot 10^{26} \mathrm{kmol}^{-1}$ and $N_{\mathrm{A}}^{\mathrm{Ch}} = (6.02336 \pm 0.00020) \cdot 10^{26} \mathrm{kmol}^{-1}$, where "Ph" presumably stands for physics and "Ch" stands for chemistry?

Comment: Perrin only contributed three of the thirteen different values (each determined by a different method) listed in his seminal publication. His values were based on measurements of Brownian motion: $(70.5, 71.5, 65) \cdot 10^{22}$. Jean Perrin, "Mouvement brownien et réalité moléculaire." *Annales de chimie et de physique*, 8th Series, Vol. 18, Sep. 1909, pp. 5-113 ([scan at BnF Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k96034900/f11.item))

Comment: @njuffa sorry, thought that was clear: although it was "called" Avogadro's Number in the text, it was *not* A.N. that they actually did describe, but the number of particles in a **kilogram**-mole, which is 1000x the number in a mole, which *is* A.N.

Comment: @njuffa ... and that value of $N_A = 6.225 \times 10^{23}$, I sincerely hope it was $N_A = 6.0225 \times 10^{23}$ or there's a serious mistake in that book.

Comment: @njuffa The kilogram-mole $\text {kg mol}$ is the number of C12 atoms in 12 kg of C12, like the gram-mole is the number of C12 atoms in 12 g of C12. The latter is "almost" the same thing as a "mole", which is Avogadro's number of things. A "gram-mole" (which is what a "mole" was before 2019) is very close to a mole, but the old term "gram-mole" is used to refer specifically to the pre-2019 definition. Similarly a kilomole is "almost" the same as a kilogram-mole.

Comment: Avogadro's number is not a real constant, in spite of its enumeration among "Physical Constants" in some sources, it is rather a calibration factor. Different values for it result from different choices both of atomic-weight scale and of macroscopic mass-scale, though in practice until recently, uncertainties of measurement practically swamped any differences due to variants in chosen standard scales of atomic weight and macroscopic mass.  For some relevant history, see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/how-did-the-early-chemists-determine-the-atomic-weight-of-hydrogen/8180#8180

Comment: @terry-s I'll let you go away and tell that to the publishers of *Data and Formulae for Engineering Students* then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 1975-76 CRC Handbook (56th edition) states:

> **Avogadro's number**. -- The number of molecules in one mole or gram-molecular weight of a substance. A number of values of the Avogadro number, which is usually denoted by $N_{A}$, have been found by various methods, generally lying within a range of 1% about the value of $6.02252 \times 10^{23}$ per gram mole.

Rounding could easily make it $6.023 \times 10^{23}$ which is still within the 1% range given.